# Stm32 cortex-m3 memory remap

Tags: memory-management, stm32, stm32l152

I am working on a stm32l152 now.

My boot up vector table is located on flash `0x0800 0000`, where there is a valid reset handler vector and stack pointer. The rest of the exception/interrupt vectors are just endless loops.
Then I setup another vector table in ram, starting at `0x2000 0000`. This vector table will have all necessary vectors.

My problem is that after doing a memory remap to map `0x0000 0000` to `0x2000 0000`, and when my interrupt fires off, it seems the mcu is still looking for the vectors in `0x0800 0000`. I have confirmed this by changing my related-vector in the flash table to that of the one in the ram table. If the flash table related-vector points to a endless loop, my program will loop endlessly. Also, I confirmed my memory remap is correct by writing/read back some memory locations across `0x0000 0000`, `0x0800 0000`, `0x2000 0000`.

Next I use the other method of changing the VTOR in the mcu to offset the vector table by `0x2000 0000`. Now, it works and the mcu will find the vector in the ram. Note that in this method, I did not do any above memory remapping.

My question is: can I use memory remap to relocate my vector table (Without changing VTOR)?

What other uses are there for memory remapping?

Can I write to `0x0000 0000` (mapped to `0x0800 0000` flash) and modify flash during runtime?

Comment: How did you do the memory remapping in the first attempt, when you were not using `SCB->VTOR`?

Comment: Question has not been refined with the information requested for several years - let's close it.

Answer (score 0):

You probably have done it right in your first attempt. However, SystemInit() function supplied by the IDE silently sets VTOR = 0x8000000, so the table at the beginning of the flash is used regardless of your memory remap settings.